# Missing entry in grub menu after kernel upgrade on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

I just Upgraded my kernels to `4.4.0.31.33` , and the new upgrade removes the old kernels so I ended up without `4.2.0-35` , the one previously used.

The problem is that grub does not see the new kernel image and everything that uses that looks for the old linux headers which are missing. 
Even when I run `sudo update-grub2` the old entries appear , but not the new ones:

    `Generating grub configuration file ...
    Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic
    Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
    Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
    done`